# Helgason's support theorem type result in 2 dimensions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integral-geometry

I had posted this question in math stackexchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4557132/complex-integral-of-a-vector-field-is-zero). Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be an open domain with smooth boundary. Identifying $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C},$ consider the following integral
$$
    \int_{\Omega} \Big(f(z)\frac{z}{|z|} - g(z)\frac{\bar z}{|z|} \Big) dz \wedge d\bar  z =0.
$$
Note that the unit vectors $\frac{z}{|z|}$ and $- \frac{\bar z}{|z|}$ are orthogonal to each other. One can write the integral as
$$
    \int_{\Omega}(f(z),g(z)) \cdot \Big(\frac{z}{|z|},-\frac{\bar z}{|z|} \Big) dz \wedge d\bar  z =0.
$$
What can we say about the vector field $(f(z),g(z))?$ Can we get any information on its 2D-curl or divergence?

Comment: As long as you don't put any constraints on $f$ and $g$, this is just an arbitrary vector field, is it not?

Comment: @Echo, I have not put any constraints. If we can assume certain regularity/ smoothness to gain some information on (f,z), then that would work.